# How do I express this proof of absolute convergence as tersely as possible?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, proof-writing

Let $x_k$ be real, for $k$ in some index set $K.$

Let $e_n$ be the $n$th-degree elementary symmetric function of $x_k,\,\,k\in K,$ i.e.
$$
e_n = \sum_{\left\{ \begin{array}c L\,\subseteq\,K \\ |L|\,=\, n \end{array} \right\}} \prod_{k\,\in\, L} x_k.
$$

Consider the following argument
\begin{align}
& e_0+e_1 + e_2 + e_3 + \cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & 1 + (x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots) \\
& \qquad {} + (x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3+ \cdots) + (x_1x_2x_3+\cdots) + \cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & (1+x_1)(1+x_2)(1+x_3) \cdots \\[10pt]
\le {} & \exp(x_1)\exp(x_2)\exp(x_3) \cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & \exp(x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots).
\end{align}
If the index set $K$ is finite, then this argument is a valid proof of an inequality.

If $K$ is infinite, then we might suppose that the series $\sum_{k\in K} x_k$ converges absolutely. In that case I would like this argument to be used in showing $\sum_{n\ge0} e_n$ also converges absolutely. That can be done fairly routinely, but **I'm wondering if there's a way to condense everything about convergence and limits and analysis into a one pithy line, where the reader might be expected to fill in the details, but they would be implicitly present in that one line. And has that been published somewhere?** (I want to use it in something where the principal focus would be on something other than how this is proved, and the argument would be just a sort of reminder of something you learned at your mother's knee.)

Comment: The inequality is clear. For the identity, the one line I would suggest, is the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @i707107 : By "the identity", you mean the equality on the line that says ${} = (1+x_1)(1+x_2)(1+x_3) \cdots \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Yes, the equality of the first line and the third.

Answer (score 2):

Alright; I've realized that what I'd already written will do it if I just make the language more severely terse. It will say that if $f_n$ is the $n$th-degree elementary symmetric function of $y_k = |x_k|,\,\,\,k\in K,$ then the series in the question **is dominated by**
\begin{align}
& f_0+f_1 + f_2 + f_3 + \cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & 1 + (y_1+y_2+y_3+\cdots) \\
& \qquad {} + (y_1y_2 + y_1y_3 + y_2y_3+ \cdots) + (y_1y_2y_3+\cdots) + \cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & (1+y_1)(1+y_2)(1+y_3) \cdots \\[10pt]
\le {} & \exp(y_1)\exp(y_2)\exp(y_3) \cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & \exp(y_1+y_2+y_3+\cdots).
\end{align}
Since everything here is nonnegative, the reader will live happily ever after.

I will just consider the phrase **"is dominated by"** to take care of all the analysis.